# Refuse complete RegEx if is follewed by other Expression JS

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

Hi Guys I am trying to find the expression 'Horas extras' but if is followed by 'No Aprobadas' refuse the complete expression. 
For example these cases don't not have to be considered 
'Horas extras no aprobadas'
'Horas extra no aprobadas'
'Hora extras no aprobada'

My regex is the following 
**horas?\s+extras?(?!\s+no\s+Aprobadas?)/gmi**

I am

I have this test link 
https://regex101.com/r/FBq6pf/1

Comment: Try `/\bhoras?\s+extras?\b(?!\s+no\s+Aprobada)/ig`

Comment: Incredible Friend, It is working now !! if is not much asking, can u explain it to me ? please

Comment: @MarcoFeregrino Because of the optional `s`. The expression matches `hora extra` because after there is `s no Aprobadas`. That's why you need a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: Nice now I understand better. Is like a wrapper of the expression to be considered. Really Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

You may "anchor" the negative lookahead with a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
/\bhoras?\s+extras?\b(?!\s+no\s+Aprobada)/ig
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBq6pf/2).

Whenever a regex engine fails to find a match, it checks all other possible paths it could take to find a valid match at the current location. It is called **backtracking**. When a pattern contains quantifiers that allow matching a variable number of chars, the regex engine goes back to them and retries a match from that location.

So, in your case, since `s?` can match 1 or 0 `s` chars, once the lookahead fails, the regex engine goes back to `horas extra` and checks if there is `\s+no\s+Aprobadas` pattern after `extra`. There is none, thus the negative lookahead returns a valid match of `horas extra`. See [your regex debugger view](https://regex101.com/r/uZmc16/1/debugger):

[image]

See, the last two steps show how the lookahead pattern is not found right after `a` and before `s` (the `s` is not matched with `\s+`).

The word boundary requires that there is a non-word char or end of string after `extra` or `extras`, so there can be no match if the engine wants to backtrack to the location before `s` (there is no word boundary position there).

Note that there would be no such problem if you had `horas?\s+extra(?!\s+no\s+Aprobadas)` regex. There is no other way to match the string other than `extra` before the lookahead, so no word boundary would be necessary.